Display the double bars chart in react native
I want to display two bars chart in react native and I checked many chart libraries and I haven't found any library for my requirements.

Problem: Display two bars in each month for booking and earning. How can I display this type of bar chart in react native?

This might be of help your use case:
https://commerce.nearform.com/open-source/victory-native/docs/cartesian/bar/bar-group
Victory Native is a powerful and customizable charting library that also supports React Native. It works good for comparison graphs

Somehow the library is not working on iOS. Getting undefined not a function on the graph screen.

This can be easily achieved using react-native-gifted-charts. You just need to use a prop named secondaryYAxis to render the Y-axis on the right side. This question has already been answered in the Discussions page of react-native-gifted charts where you can see the exact code to render your chart.
